# Como gravar em cache em c# .NET uma informação para vários usuários?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Eu tenho uma lista de objetos, e gostaria que cada usuário que acessasse uma página, adicionasse os objetos dela ao cache. E que esse cache valesse para a próxima pessoa que acessasse a mesma url.

Exemplo, eu tenho a url "/objetos/id-6", o primeiro usuário que acessá-la vai gravar o cache, e assim todos os próximos usuários que acessarem essa url, não precisarão consultar o banco pois puxarão os dados do cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedro, você tem algumas opções.
Memory cache ou cache distribuído, por exemplo Redis.

No memorycache você pode armazenar a key/value, conforme o exemplo:

```
 protected MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("CachingProvider");

    static readonly object padlock = new object();

    protected virtual void AddItem(string key, object value)
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            cache.Add(key, value, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RemoveItem(string key)
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            cache.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    protected virtual object GetItem(string key, bool remove)
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            var res = cache[key];

            if (res != null)
            {
                if (remove == true)
                    cache.Remove(key);
            }
            else
            {
                WriteToLog("CachingProvider-GetItem: Don't contains key: " + key);
            }

            return res;
        }
    }
```

Aí seria bacana você criar uma camada de cache na sua aplicação, quando o banco fosse alterado ou algo do tipo invalidasse o seu cache e você atualizaria ele novamente.

Creio que para sua aplicação o MemoryCache já te atenda, tem mais informações de onde tirei esse código:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756423/How-to-Cache-Objects-Simply-using-System-Runtime-C